# Can ANESA be used to diagnose pathologies?

Tags: medical-science, healthcare

I stumbled upon the [Automatic Non-invasive Express Screening Analyzer (ANESA)](http://www.mdevice.eu/en/certificates/article-65.html) device.

In the description it reads

> ANESA Automatic Non-invasive Express Screening Analyzer determines the state of organism, its functional, hemodynamic balance, water - and gas exchange from position of homeostasis, which is interrelated with fermentation and immunologic correction. Determines metabolizm and patologies of nerve, heart and circulatory systems, internal organs, supporting and motoring systems, blood circulation
>
> The non-invasive test for a short time from 3 to 12 minutes, after that you get 130 parameters which characterizes the state of the human body. Among these there are several indicators what would otherwise be determined only by surgery.

So this is either a technological wonder or just an other scam. What drew my attention is that they claim this device got an "Award of the German Academy of Natural Sciences" (and "Crystal Diploma of the Ministry of Health United Arab Emirates", whatever this means).

It also states that it is certified in EU, Ukraine and Russia, although they don't explicitly state what is certified to do. In the [page](http://www.mdevice.eu/en/certification_in_es/page-1/) about their certification they state something I cannot really comprehend.

I couldn't find anything remotely scientific about this device with a casual search on-line so I thought I should ask here. So, does anyone know anything about it and whether it can diagnose pathologies that would normally take surgery to detect?

Comment: FWIW: Scientific American promoted it: http://www.scientificamerican.com/video/anesa-tests-blood-without-needle/

Comment: There's another machine that claims the same [here](http://www.amp.jmpl.eu/). They both claim to be based on the patented, and apperntly very mysterious "[Malychin Pulawski](http://scholar.google.co.uk/scholar?q=Malychin+Pulawski+&btnG=&hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5)" method.

Comment: By reading [the manual](http://www.mdevice.eu/files/amp/ANESAMANUALEN.pdf) you can see that it has five temp probes and nothing else to scan the patient.

Comment: [The certificates](http://www.anesa.tc/en/certificates) say absolutely nothing about the device's functionality.  The five on the linked page are 1) a copyright certificate, 2) a patent (which isn't proof of functionality), 3) some sort of Ukrainian commerce certificate (which explicitly disclaims any guarantee), 4) an ISO 13485 certification, and 5) an ISO 9001 certification.  The ISO certifications are essentially proof of consistent quality, not of functionality (you can make ISO-9000 piles of shit, as long as you document the process and show you follow it).

Comment: @Mark, thanks for the explanation. I expected this, but I wasn't sure.

Comment: So, is there any indication that this thing actually works?

Answer (score 2):

There is an encouraging study that shows promising results, although with limitations and in need of confirmation:

> Despite  of  the  study  limitations,  the  automatic non-invasive  analyser  (ANESA)  is  shown  as  a reliable and promising screening method in usual clinical  practice  for  most  of  the  analyzed parameters  as an  alternative  to standard blood extraction.  However, more  studies are  required to strengthen the consistency of the results.

["Comparison of the Automatic Non-invasive Express Screening Analyser (ANESA)® for Clinical Analytical Parameters"](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/306096117_Comparison_of_the_Automatic_Non-invasive_Express_Screening_Analyser_ANESAR_for_Clinical_Analytical_Parameters),  Antoni Sicras-Mainar and Luis Collado-Yurrita